# How can I convert this table-based layout to use semantic html with css-based layout?

Tags: css, semantic-markup

[image: Layout]

In the image above, most of the html is semantic, using css to manage the look of it all. Despite my best efforts, though, I had to resort to using a table to get the segment on the right to stay where it is and allow its inner elements to wrap fluidly when it gets too big for the screen, like this:
[image: Too wide for the browser]

I know that it's preferable if tables are only used for "tabular data," but I have never found a good way to force elements to do this without using tables. Has anybody solved this problem?

Comment: What's the _exact_ problem you're solving? Allowing text wrapping to happen in a div container? That doesn't sound like a big problem, since it should happen by default.

Comment: If I use divs to hold the "Select Layout" area on the left and the buttons and tabs on the right, then as soon as the buttons or tabs exceed the browser width, the entire panel on the right flows down underneath the Layout list. I want it to stay on the right, and make the list of buttons (for example) start wrapping instead.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using list-items? Generally when creating menu elements, it's better to use UL->LI instead of span or div

Comment: The lists of buttons and tabs use list items. The only table here has two cells: one to hold the list of layouts on the left, and the other to hold the lists of buttons and tabs at the right.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the width of it. This is difficult to do without seeing the exact way you are doing this, because CSS is dependent on parent sizes, etc.

I would look into the CSS property min-width, too.

Comment: I want the width of the panel at the right (with layout tabs and buttons) to adjust itself to take up whatever space is left after the list of layout buttons at the left has taken up the space it needs.